# What's the deal with "Trials" in C5.0 ruleModels when trained with caret?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

When I train a C5.0 ruleModel with caret I get multiple "Trials" - what is this about?

My code looks somewhat like the following - only that this example here results in an error - no idea why - it does work with my actual data:

```
ruleModel <- train(churn ~ ., churnTrain, method = "C5.0", maximize=TRUE)
summary(ruleModel)
```

Comment: the `trails` is a parameter for increasing the number of boosting iterations, this parameter is standard on the `C5.0` package. So look up what exactly is boosting (short: learn from weak learners each iteration until the number given with `trails`)